# Scheduled task not created with silent installation

Tags: scheduled-tasks, installshield, installshield-le

I've created a setup file using InstallShield Limited Edition, and I have a custom action that creates a scheduled task in the "After Setup Completed Success dialog" custom actions folder for installation:

```
schtasks.exe /create /xml "[INSTALLDIR]\task definition.xml" /tn "My Task"
```

If I run the setup as administrator, or I start it from a system context, everything goes fine.

However, if I run it silently, with the `/S /v/qn` command line parameters, everything works except for the task, which is not created.

How can I create the task also with a silent installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of reason this could happen.  If for example you have this running as a custom action in your UI sequence,  the UI sequence doesn't run under a silent install.  You would need to put it in the Execute sequence.

Comment: I moved the custom action under "After Register Product" and now it works, thanks!